# I am wondering why scroll get disturb when i full screen the HTML 5 video

Tags: html, scroll, html5-video

Currently i am using Html 5 video, when i click on full screen button it eventually disturb the scroll position. Automatically, the scroll position point to the top.

I have created a scenario, it's working fine on the Firefox browser however the scroll get disturb when i use the chrome browser.
Note: Please scroll to mid before tapping on maximize button of the video

Please click on the below link for watching the demo.
Demo is here

```
    `enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/1re7jkLf/
```

Comment: please post your markup, and include some sort of way for us to recreate the problem you are having. You're giving us nothing to work off.

Comment: I have created a demo please check it